# "Class" type redefinition error C2011 in C++

Tags: c++

Here's my header file:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#pragma once
class Something {
    
public:
    
    //Screen dimension constants
    int SCREEN_WIDTHS;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHTS;

    //Starts up SDL and creates window
    bool inits();

    //Loads media
    bool loadMediases();

    //Frees media and shuts down SDL
    void closes();

    Something(int height);

    int mains();

    //Loads individual image
    SDL_Surface* loadSurfaces(std::string path);

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* gWindows;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurfaces;

    //The images that correspond to a keypress
    SDL_Surface* gKeyPressSurfaceses[5];

    //Current displayed image
    SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurfaces;
};
#endif
```

Here's my cpp file:

```
//Using SDL, standard IO, and strings

#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Something.h"
class Something {
    
public:
    
    //Screen dimension constants
    int SCREEN_WIDTHS = 640;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHTS = 480;

    //Key press surfaces constants
    enum KeyPressSurfaceses
    {
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
        KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL
    };


    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* gWindows = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* gScreenSurfaces = NULL;

    //The images that correspond to a keypress
    SDL_Surface* gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL];

    //Current displayed image
    SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurfaces = NULL;

    Something(int height) {
        SCREEN_HEIGHTS = height;
    }

    bool inits()
    {
        //Initialization flag
        bool success = true;

        //Initialize SDL
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        {
            printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create window
            gWindows = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTHS, SCREEN_HEIGHTS, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
            if (gWindows == NULL)
            {
                printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get window surface
                gScreenSurfaces = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindows);
            }
        }

        return success;
    }

    bool loadMedias()
    {
        //Loading success flag
        bool success = true;

        //Load default surface
        gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT] = loadSurfaces("resources/images/press.bmp");
        if (gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to load default image!\n");
            success = false;
        }

        //Load up surface
        gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP] = loadSurfaces("resources/images/up.bmp");
        if (gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to load up image!\n");
            success = false;
        }

        //Load down surface
        gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN] = loadSurfaces("resources/images/down.bmp");
        if (gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to load down image!\n");
            success = false;
        }

        //Load left surface
        gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT] = loadSurfaces("resources/images/left.bmp");
        if (gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to load left image!\n");
            success = false;
        }

        //Load right surface
        gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT] = loadSurfaces("resources/images/right.bmp");
        if (gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to load right image!\n");
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }

    void closes()
    {
        //Deallocate surfaces
        for (int i = 0; i < KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL; ++i)
        {
            SDL_FreeSurface(gKeyPressSurfaceses[i]);
            gKeyPressSurfaceses[i] = NULL;
        }

        //Destroy window
        SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindows);
        gWindows = NULL;

        //Quit SDL subsystems
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    SDL_Surface* loadSurfaces(std::string path)
    {
        //Load image at specified path
        SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
        if (loadedSurface == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError());
        }

        return loadedSurface;
    }


    int mains(int argc, char* args[])
    {
        //Start up SDL and create window
        if (!inits())
        {
            printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //Load media
            if (!loadMedias())
            {
                printf("Failed to load media!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                //Main loop flag
                bool quit = false;

                //Event handler
                SDL_Event e;

                //Set default current surface
                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT];

                //While application is running
                while (!quit)
                {
                    //Handle events on queue
                    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                    {
                        //User requests quit
                        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                        {
                            quit = true;
                        }
                        //User presses a key
                        else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                        {
                            //Select surfaces based on key press
                            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                            {
                            case SDLK_UP:
                                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP];
                                break;

                            case SDLK_DOWN:
                                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN];
                                break;

                            case SDLK_LEFT:
                                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT];
                                break;

                            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT];
                                break;

                            default:
                                gCurrentSurfaces = gKeyPressSurfaceses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Apply the current image
                    SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurfaces, NULL, gScreenSurfaces, NULL);

                    //Update the surface
                    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindows);
                }
            }
        }

        //Free resources and close SDL
        closes();

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Why does it keep throwing a "Class" type redefinition error? How can I fix this? I've tried everything but I just run into more problems. I saw some posts relating the issue to defining the class twice, but getting rid of the class definition in the cpp and using classname::functionname just causes more errors.

I know this is a stupid problem to have, I'm a beginning C++ programmer using tutorials and Visual Studio.

Comment: Please mind your language.

Comment: well it means what you do. You define the class in the .h file and then redefine it in the .cpp file.

Comment: I bet you are a C# programmer. In C#, you can have _partial classes_. That concept doesn't exist in C++ (unfortunately). A single class declaration is allowed.

Comment: Basically what the error says: You have defined 2 classes with the same name. The syntax `class name {...};` is a definition. Get rid of the class definition in the cpp file and define the functions like this: void ClassName::closes() {...}

Comment: @HerpDerpityPurple In short, C++ is not the same as C#, although quite a lot of features are similar.

Comment: Extract a [mcve] before even thinking about asking here, please. You might find the error yourself that way. As new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

In your .cpp file you have completely redeclared `class Something`. That's not how you do it if you want to just put the implementations of functions in the .cpp file.

The syntax in there should be like:

```
bool Something::inits()
{
    // implementation ...
}

bool Something::loadMedias()
{
    // implementation ...
}
```

And so on

Comment: I've tried that before and I just tried it again. I still keep getting a bunch of errors where Visual Studio says it "expects a declaration" on if statements and functions.

Comment: @HerpDerpityPurple that would be an unrelated error. You probably want to ask a different question with a [mcve]. My second advice is don't write so much code without compiling and testing.

Comment: @drescherjm to be honest I have no idea how I'd reduce this down...

Comment: @HerpDerpityPurple Perhaps make a simple example class with one function. Try to get the syntax to work to split the implementation and declaration in the .cpp and .h files. If that works, then start adding things until you run into a problem you can't solve - if that happens, then post a question about that specific situation.

Comment: Are you sure that in the cpp file you defined `bool Something::inits() { // implementation }` and not just `bool inits() { // implementation}` the `Something::` part is essential.

Comment: @drescherjm I did that in the cpp file, and it'll just give me errors on random whiles, ifs and variables, things like "error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'TheDumbestFuckingThingEverCreatedByMan::gWindows'"

Comment: Google that error. It means you need an instance of the class  to use gWindows.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm also getting things like "type 'int' unexpected" and "missing ';' before '{'", which is concerning